# How to make an if statement based on text

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

So I can't figure out how to put text in the statement because I need it to be based off of text like so

```js
function onEdit() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Class');
  var char_class = sheet.getRange('Traits!L3').getValue();
  if (char_class == Warlock) {
    sheet.getRange('A7:D7').breakApart();
    sheet.getRange('A7:D7').mergeAcross();
  } else {
    if (char_class == Fighter) {
      sheet.getRange('A7:D7').breakApart();
      sheet.getRange('A7:B7').mergeAcross();
    } else {
  }
}
```

It might be working with the code itself, but I think it's just not recognizing the class correctly. So if your class is warlock you get the fancy merged cell and if you are a fighter you do not

Comment: Your strings need to be in quotes (`"Fighter"`) in order to actually be strings.

Answer (score 3):

Quotes should be around what you want to check to make it a string, or else you're checking against the value of the variable `Warlock` - which is `undefined`

You should also use an `if / else if` instead of nested `if`s and use [strong equality `===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Strict_equality_using) instead of [loose equality `==`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Loose_equality_using)

```js
function onEdit() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Class');
  var char_class = sheet.getRange('Traits!L3').getValue();

  if (char_class === 'Warlock') {
    sheet.getRange('A7:D7').breakApart();
    sheet.getRange('A7:D7').mergeAcross();
  } else if (char_class === 'Fighter') {
    sheet.getRange('A7:D7').breakApart();
    sheet.getRange('A7:B7').mergeAcross();
  } else {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the code break apart and merge the cells an intended

Comment: I don't know, I don't have the sheet to test - the if statement logic is correct